# parameterization of xpath query to prevent injection attack

Tags: xml, xpath

as xpath injection attack is striking the website so we need to protect the xml document as a solution parameterization of xpath query come into existence. Please help if any anyone can explain what does parameterization of xpath query mean? and how this parameterization helps to prevent xpath injection attacks? and why there is a need to encrypt these parameters?

Comment: Related: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection.

Answer (score 2):

Parameterization means that instead of constructing your XPath expression by string concatenation

```
"//x[y = '" + param + "']"
```

you construct it with a parameter

```
"//x[y = $param]"
```

and supply a value for the parameter $param when you execute the expression. The way in which you supply parameter values depends on the XPath API you are using, and may not be possible with all APIs (e.g. the DOM selectNodes() method).